# Cluster quality measures

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, data-mining, evaluation

Does Matlab provide any facility for evaluating clustering methods? (cluster compactness and cluster separation. ....) 
Or is there any toolbox for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in Matlab, but [ELKI](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/) (Java) provides a dozen or so cluster quality measures for evaluation.

Answer (score 5):

Matlab provides Silhouette index and there is a toolbox [CVAP: Cluster Validity Analysis Platform](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14620) for Matlab. Which includes following validity indexes:

- Davies-Bouldin
- Calinski-Harabasz
- Dunn index
- R-squared index
- Hubert-Levin (C-index)
- Krzanowski-Lai index
- Hartigan index
- Root-mean-square standard deviation (RMSSTD) index
- Semi-partial R-squared (SPR) index
- Distance between two clusters (CD) index
- weighted inter-intra index
- Homogeneity index
- Separation index

Note that you might need precompiled [LIBRA binaries](http://wis.kuleuven.be/stat/robust/LIBRA) for your platform.

Answer (score 4):

You can try [Silhouette plot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/silhouette.html) from the Statistical toolbox.

For an example see [this documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/bq_679x-18.html).

Comment: Thank. But I want use validation function as fitness/goal function for particle swarm clustering.

Answer (score 3):

Be aware that the Silhouette in Matlab has some strange behavior for singleton clusters. It assigns a score of 1 for singletons, when, for me, a more reasonable approach would be to give 0 for these clusters. In the Matlab implementation, if you give number of clusters as number of objects, Silhouette will give you a score of 1.