# How do I choose k when using k-means clustering with Silhouette function?

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, k-means

I've been studying about k-means clustering, and one big thing which is not clear is what Silhouette function really tell to me?

i know it shows that what appropriate k should be detemine but i cant understand what mean of silhouette function really say to me?

i read somewhere, if the mean of silhouette is less than 0.5 your clustering is not valid.

thanks for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the definition of [silhouette](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/silhouette.html) :

> **Silhouette Value**
>
> The silhouette value for each point is a measure of how similar that
>   point is to points in its own cluster compared to points in other
>   clusters, and ranges from -1 to +1.
>
> The silhouette value for the ith point, Si, is defined as
>
> Si = (bi-ai)/ max(ai,bi) where ai is the average distance from the ith
>   point to the other points in the same cluster as i, and bi is the
>   minimum average distance from the ith point to points in a different
>   cluster, minimized over clusters.

This method just compares the intra-group similarity to closest group similarity. If any data member average distance to other members of the same cluster is higher than average distance to some other cluster members, then this value is negative and clustering is not successful. On the other hand, silhuette values close to 1 indicates a successful clustering operation. 0.5 is not an exact measure for clustering.

Comment: thanks for your answer.finally i know if there is a negative silhouette in data, the clustering is not valid any more. as i said before the mean of silhouette is 0.46 but there is a negative silhouette value with some data, what should i do now? it means that the kmean algorithm is not working for me or...?

Comment: @user2691280, you can increase the parameter k for k-means clustering to decrease the possibility of negative silhoette values.

Comment: i have reall data and this is related to the Composite failure. im studing Mechanics. we have 3 failure mod in composite. it should be 3 someway. when i normalize data between -2,+2 the mean of silhouette increase... is normalizing has effected to this in positive way?

Comment: @user2691280, normalizing the data in a piecewise linear way may change the silhoutte values in positive or negative direction depending on the data. If cluster assignments did not change with respect to the original case, it does not necessarily indicates a clustering improvemeent.

Comment: are you sure the negative value show that the clustering is not valid? i try with k=4, but there is negative value in there. please see my silhouette value [MediaFire](http://www.mediafire.com/?32rydsb2v12720d)

Comment: @user2691280: A negative value of silhouette coefficient does not necessarily mean you have an invalid clustering, just that the clusters are not quite highly dense and well separated. Note that such concept of "goodness-of-fit" is not always the best evaluation measure, especially if the data itself is not dense that way. Think for example of a dataset consisting of two co-centric rings of 2D points, each comprising a cluster. The inter- and intra- distances are not very different, and the silhouette score will not be high. Of course simple kmeans would fail on such non-linear dataset.

Comment: so what kind of Clustering do you prefer? i optimized the CostFunction of Kmean with  Imperialist Competitive Alghorithm. the minimum of CostFunction is optimized better but the mean of silhouette value is not change. i think silhouette value is not depend on alghorithm, i depend on DataSet.

Comment: @user2691280: [silhouette score](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silhouette_%28clustering%29) does favor algorithms that optimize for compactness and separation of clusters (such as kmeans and density-based algorithms), since those algorithms have a compatible optimization criteria as their goal. All I'm saying is that you should be aware of the limitation of silhouette as a cluster validation method in general..

Comment: so i know there are a lot of validation but how many of them is used in matlab? (i mean the method which have a function in matlab...) which method do you prefer?

Comment: I dont think MATLAB ships with many methods, but there are lots of implementations online. Here's a related question with some answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365616/cluster-quality-measures, where this one is mentioned: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14620

Answer (score 0):

@fatihk gave a good citation;

- additionally, you may think about the Silhouette value as a degree of
  **how clusters overlap with each other**, i.e. -1: overlap perfectly,
  +1: clusters are perfectly separable;
- BUT low Silhouette values for a particular algorithm does NOT mean that there are no clusters, rather it means that the algorithm used cannot separate clusters and you may consider tune your algorithm or use a different algorithm (think about K-means for concentric circles, vs DBSCAN).

Answer (score -2):

There is an explicit formula associated with the elbow method to automatically determine the number of clusters. The formula tells you about the strength of the elbow(s) being detected when using the elbow method to determine the number of clusters, see [here](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/how-to-automatically-determine-the-number-of-clusters-in-your-dat). See illustration here:
[Enhanced Elbow rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sKFs.png)

Comment: I can't see my picture. It is in my article, but I wish it would show up here too.